# Cannot push to a remote git repository after adding ssh public key

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to push some code to my git repository from a remote server. I have generated new ssh keys using the command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "<my-email>@xx.com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_dy
```

I have added `id_rsa_dy.pub` to my GitHub account. However, when I try to execute the command:

```
git push -u origin main
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Running `ssh -T git@github.com` results in:

```
Hi <xx>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I am unsure of what to do next.

Comment: Is the repository URL definitely correct? And are you definitely using that key? Because that isn’t the default key file name used in connections.